# Solr schema questions

Tags: solr, schema

just compiled some hopefully basic solr questions regarding schemas.

My situation: previously had a multi-cored instance of solr, each core containing a different document structure. Although information in documents in one core was related to documents in other different cores, specific legal constraints forced us to keep that data scatered in indepent instances. Therefore each time a request to the solr instance was issued, several cores were queried and the client app "merged" and structured the responses of the several separate cores. For the sake of exemplification: suppose we were a music store and stupid as it sounds, we had a core for CDs, a core for DVDs, a core for tapes, etc each having its own different schema; and then when an employee checked the stock all of these cores returned their responses for the app in the employee's computer to read, process the different structures, and present the results as one unified list.

Well, the legal constraints have been lifted and we're now merging the cores together, so far relying heavily in dynamicFields for schema flexibility. That however brings a whole new lot of challenges and a few doubts as well:

1 - What's better: Having a reduced number of documents each with a huge number of fields (we're talking hundreds, occasionaly a thousand here or there, all indexed) or instead scattering the information in several minor-sized documents? From what I've been reading in theory the first approach would be advisable, but I don't think that any of the cases considered this amount of fields.

2 - Is it possible to perform any sort of relational search? What I mean is something like having the following documents:

```
     <doc>
        <ID>ALB@1234</ID>
        <artist_t>Metallica</artist>
        <album_t>Saint Anger</album>        
      </doc>

      <doc>
        <ID>PROD@12</ID>
        <AlbID>ALB@1234</AlbID>
        <format_t>CD</format_t>
        <price_m>8.99</price_m>     
      </doc>

      <doc>
        <ID>PROD@13</ID>
        <AlbID>ALB@1234</AlbID>         
        <format_t>MP3</format_t>
        <price_m>3.99</price_m>     
      </doc>
```

and then upon performing a search for Metallica have all three documents retrieved? Keep in mind that the approach of storing the info of the last two documents in the first one as multivalued is not really an option, because as far as I know there would be no way of p.e. retrieving the right format that matched a range search by price.

3 - Alternatively, is it possible to define some sort of subdocument structure as part of a document, as in a multilevel document? Again I don't mean poly or multiValued fields here, since as far as I know they aren't suitable for more complex and structured info. Was 
 thinking of something along the lines of:

```
    <doc>
        <ID>ALB@1234</ID>
        <artist_t>Metallica</artist>
        <album_t>Saint Anger</album>        
        <formats>
            <format_x><ID>PROD@13</ID><AlbID>ALB@1234</AlbID><format_t>MP3</format_t><price_m>3.99</price_m></format_x>     
            <format_x><ID>PROD@12</ID><AlbID>ALB@1234</AlbID><format_t>CD</format_t><price_m>8.99</price_m></format_x>      
        </formats>          
      </doc>
```

4 - A consideration: of course, this situation can be fixed by modeling the schema like described on 2) and performing more than one query to the server, but that's not really the most desirable solution.

Looking forward to any comment or suggestion. Bashing is a bit less welcome but still acceptable, just go easy on me. ;) And I'm sorry if these questions sound stupid but really needing some help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends how you want to structure the data and how you want the search to happen on the data.
There is no limit on the number of fields on the document.
If you can normalize the data within the same document, would help you to retreive the document and all the related details at once.

For relational search, Solr has introduced a feature [Solr Join](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join), which will help you to join documents.
However, this is available only with Solr Trunk. So unless you can work with Solr Trunk build, this would not be an option for you.

Solr does not have subdocument structure. However, you can try using multivalued fields to map the content. Or even use delimited values.

```
<album>
    <cd_id>
        <str>cd_1</str>
        <str>cd_2</str>
    </cd_id>
    <cd_price>
        <str>cd_1_price</str>
        <str>cd_2_price</str>
    </cd_price>
</album>
```

The order of the multivalued fields should be maintained (so you can map cd_1 to cd_1_price with the position 1) and you should be able to recreate the data at client side.

Comment: Great to know about Solr Join, had never heard about it before. I'll be sure look into it, even if I think that there is no chance of implementing a trunk build. Regarding the rest of your answer: multivalued fields is not an option because my real life situation involves a few more levels of depth and very complex structures, all of them fully searchable. I'd also like to hear your opinion in the 1) question; I know there is no field limit, but would like to know what is the recommended approach: less documents, huge data in each VS more documents, smaller ammount of data each.

Comment: Again from my perspective its depends, I would like to organize the data easier to fit in my requirements. If the collection is small less documents with more fields might work quite well for you. However, if its a hugh collection you need to check the FieldCache objects. These objects cache the value of a field for the total set of documents available in the index, and you cannot able to tune this cache through the Solr configuration, which may lead memory issues. Its not an expert opinion though and Solr forums would be a best place to get these answered.